# Is it possible to do biometric login through a React-Native WebView, to a Salesforce Community?

Tags: react-native, authentication, webview, salesforce, biometrics

I have a unique situation where I am trying to put a salesforce community site in a React-Native webview, but I want to add another way to login. I already have the standard username and password login in the webview, but I want to have the option to do a fingerprint/face id login. The problem is, since I am using a webview to display my site, is it even possible to leverage my hardware biometric capabilities and send it to salesforce to allow login through the webview?

I've done research regarding this, but I've come up short. I have seen a bunch of articles referring to lightning login, but I don't want users of the app to download an authenticator app just so they can login with their fingerprint/face id in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up determining a possible solution to our problem that we are going to proceed with.

Our problem was that even if the mobile device was authorized, that did not mean that the session in the webview was authorized and vice-versa. Separately authenticating them was not an option in our case because we wanted the bio-metric login to also log the user in through the webview as well. In order to solve this problem without over-complicating the solution, we thought it would be best if we could hit an endpoint in the webview url with some credentials that would verify that the user is who they say they are.

By hitting our

```
https://.../services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=...
&redirect_uri=...
```

end point requesting an access token, we can use this as verification that the user is who they say they are.

Once we have have our access token in the react-native application we utilize frontdoor.jsp which allows a session_id to be passed in order to skip having to login with username and password. The session_id value is the access token obtained earlier. Our endpoint looks something like this:

```
https://.../secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=...&retURL=...
```

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_frontdoorjsp.htm&type=5

Where the bio-metric part comes in is the getting of access token and modifying our webview url to instead redirect to the frontdoor endpoint if the user successfully authenticates bio-metrically.

We will be handling the refresh token flow using the bio-metric piece as well.

Hopefully this is able to help someone else who might run into this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a Connected App that gives you an Access Token and a Refresh Token via OAuth.

User First Time => Gets redirected to the Webview with OAuth, you get the Access Token and the Refresh Token that you store on the user's phone.

All the other times => User is asked for TouchID, you take the stored refresh token, you get a new access token with the refresh flow from the connected app.

All your Api calls will have the `Authorization : Bearer <Access_Token>`.